# Find the volume of the solid of revolution formed when the region bounded by $y=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x^3}}$ and $y=0$ is revolved about the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

[Image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufUQY.jpg)

The question is : Analytically find the volume of the solid of revolution formed when the region bounded by $y=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x^3}}$  and
$y=0$ is revolved about the $x$-axis or indicate the volume is infinite.
[image: Graph of function]

I don’t know whether to consider the part of the curve in quadrant 2.

Does bounded mean to not consider that ?

Comment: Most teachers I know would expect you to ignore that part, but perhaps you should confirm with your teacher just to be sure.

Comment: You need to ask your teacher or do two solutions, one for $x\ge 1$ and one for $x \ge 1$ with $x<0$.

Comment: The figure in quadrant II is not bounded by the given graphs since it also has a boundary along $x=0$. So one has a plausible reason not to consider it.

Comment: I don't know why this question has received a down vote or a close recommendation. OP is not asking for a solution to the exercise. Rather they are asking for clarification on what 'bounded by two curves' means in this context. It is a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: I would solve the problem with $x\ge1$ and put a note as to why you are ignoring $x<0.$  Furthermore, the integral does not converge if you consider the region to the right of 0.